# Frobenius norm inequality: If $A \succ 0$ and $\| r \|_F < \|R \|_F$, can we conclude: $\| A^{-1/2} r A^{1/2} \|_F \leq \| A^{-1/2} R A^{1/2} \|_F$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, positive-definite, matrix-norms

I am working to prove a good upper bound on a matrix Frobenius norm. In what follows, I have a positive definite matrices $A \in \mathcal{S}^n_{++}$, and two symmetric matrices $r$ and $R$ where I am working under the assumption that the size of $r$ is controlled by $R$, that is;
$$ \| r \|_F \leq \beta \| R \|_F,$$
where $\beta \in (0,1)$.

Now, in my work I have a term of the form
$$ \| A^{-1/2} r A^{1/2} \|_F$$
where $A^{1/2}$ denotes the symmetric square root of $A$. However, the only assumption I am making on $r$ is that it is a symmetric matrix, and I do not wish to make any further simplifying assumptions. Thus, is there a way to show:
$$ \| A^{-1/2} r A^{1/2} \|_F \leq \beta \| A^{-1/2} R A^{1/2} \|_F?$$

I think we can use the fact that $\| \cdot \|_F$ is submultiplicative to arrive at:
\begin{align*}
 \| A^{-1/2} r A^{1/2} \|_F &\leq  \| A^{-1/2} \|_F \|r\|_F \|A^{1/2} \|_F \\
&= \kappa_F (A^{1/2}) \| r \|_F \\
&\leq \beta \kappa_F (A^{1/2}) \| R\|_F \\
&= \beta \| A^{-1/2} \|_F \| R \|_F \| A^{1/2} \|_F <\| A^{-1/2} \|_F \| R \|_F \| A^{1/2} \|_F,
\end{align*}
where $\kappa_F (\cdot)$ denote the Frobenius condition number of a matrix. However, I am not sure if this gives precisely the conclusion that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality does not hold.

For instance, let
$$
r=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1/2\\1/2&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad
R=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2&1/3\\1/3&1/2\end{bmatrix},\qquad
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&4\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then
$$
\|r\|_F=\frac{\sqrt2}2<\frac{\sqrt{13}}{\sqrt{18}}=\|R\|_F,
$$
while
$$
\|A^{-1/2}rA^{1/2}\|_F=\frac{\sqrt{17}}4>\frac{\sqrt{35}}6=\|A^{-1/2}RA^{1/2}\|_F
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, the result doesn't hold in general, but perhaps a light assumption would be that there *exists* some $\beta \in (0,1)$ for which the result does hold?

Comment: The way you've written it, no. You are just replacing $R$ with $\beta R$.